# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda

I know there is a lot of topics like this one, but I cant find the answer.

In code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>TabelaModel</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Druzyna)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Druzyna)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Druzyna);
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LiczbaMeczy)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox(model => model.LiczbaMeczy)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LiczbaMeczy)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LiczbaGoliStrzelonych)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LiczbaGoliStrzelonych)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LiczbaGoliStrzelonych)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Compiler is throwing an exception in line:

```
@Html.TextBox(model => model.LiczbaMeczy)
```

I have put a System.Linq, System.Data.Entity in model, in view, in controller, but still nothing. It's working when i replace @Html.TextBox into @Html.EditorFor, but i really would like to avoid this. My model class:

```
namespace GridViewTest.Models
{
    public class TabelaModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Druzyna { get; set; }
        [Required (ErrorMessage="*")]
        public string LiczbaMeczy { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public int LiczbaGoliStrzelonych { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Could You help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `TextBoxFor` (not `TextBox`):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LiczbaMeczy)
```

That will take the lambda expression.

Comment: Thank You, it's working now !. I Will accept answer in 10 minutes :). I was sure that @Html.TextBox will be good for this..